# Checking ABP permissions from claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, aspnetboilerplate, claims

I am using ABP version 3.9 for ASP.NET Core. We have an existing Identity Server 4 instance that provides role information in the form of claims (via OIDC). I would like to hook into ABP's permissions system for dynamic menu-ing, among other things. Since I'm not using a local [Identity Server](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server)<sup>1</sup> implementation, I don't see a way to convert the claims to permissions.

My thought is to use custom middleware to handle it like this:

```
public class ClaimsToAbpPermissionsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ClaimsToAbpPermissionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get user
        ClaimsPrincipal user = context.User;

        // foreach claim of type "role"
        var roleClaims = user.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "role");
        foreach (Claim claim in roleClaims)
        {
            switch (claim.Value)
            {
                case "TestResults":
                    // Assign applicable permission
                    // ...
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to apply the permissions. [User Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management)<sup>2</sup> suggests using `UserManager`, which appears to have the necessary functionality.

First, `Abp.ZeroCore` doesn't have this class. Can I use `Abp.Zero` in an ASP.NET Core app?

Second, it looks like `Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUserManager` has similar functionality. Can I use this? However, I'm not sure how to inject this into `Startup`, as it requires some types for injecting `AbpUserManager<TRole, TUser>` and I'm not clear on what types to use.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Additionally, is what I'm trying feasible? Is there a better approach?

The issue is that I'm not using Module Zero's [User Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management)<sup>2</sup>. All of our users are in a separate ASP.NET Identity (Identity Server) implementation, and I'm using the template from ABP that doesn't include the models/pages for user/tenant/role, so I don't have the types to inject `AbpUserManager<TRole, TUser>`.

<sup>1</sup>https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server
<sup>2</sup>https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management

**Update:** So I implemented IPermissionChecker as per the answer below:

PermissionChecker (not in love with the switch, but am going to refactor once it's working):

```
public class PermissionChecker : IPermissionChecker, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public PermissionChecker(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public  Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(string permissionName)
    {
        bool isGranted = false;

        // Get user
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        // Get claims of type "role"
        var roleClaims = user.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "role");

        // Check for applicable permission based on role permissions
        foreach (Claim claim in roleClaims)
        {
            switch (claim.Value)
            {
                case "TestResults":
                    // Assign applicable permission
                    // ...
                    if(permissionName.ToLowerInvariant() == "TestResults".ToLowerInvariant())
                    {
                        isGranted = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "About":
                    // Assign applicable permission
                    // ...
                    if (permissionName.ToLowerInvariant() == "AboutView".ToLowerInvariant())
                    {
                        isGranted = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Account":
                    // Assign applicable permission
                    // ...
                    if (permissionName.ToLowerInvariant() == "AccountView".ToLowerInvariant())
                    {
                        isGranted = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (isGranted)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //return new Task<bool> 
        return Task.FromResult(isGranted);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(UserIdentifier user, string permissionName)
    {
        return IsGrantedAsync(permissionName);
    }
}
```

AuthorizationProvider:

```
public class MyAuthProvider : AuthorizationProvider
{
    public override void SetPermissions(IPermissionDefinitionContext context)
    {
        var about = context.CreatePermission("AboutView");
        var account = context.CreatePermission("AccountView");
        var testResults = context.CreatePermission("TestResults");
    }
}
```

Module Initialization:

```
public class CentralPortalCoreModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.Auditing.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

        CentralPortalLocalizationConfigurer.Configure(Configuration.Localization);
        IocManager.Register<IPermissionChecker, PermissionChecker>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
        Configuration.Authorization.Providers.Add<MyAuthProvider>();
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(CentralPortalCoreModule).GetAssembly());
    }
}
```

Navigation Provider:

```
public override void SetNavigation(INavigationProviderContext context)
    {
        context.Manager.MainMenu
            .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.Home,
                    L("HomePage"),
                    url: "",
                    icon: "fa fa-home"
                    )
            ).AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.About,
                    L("About"),
                    url: "Home/About",
                    icon: "fa fa-info",
                    requiredPermissionName: "AboutView",
                    requiresAuthentication: true
                    )
            ).AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                "Results",
                L("Results"),
                url: "Results",
                icon: "fa fa-tasks",
                requiredPermissionName: "TestResults"
                )
            )
            .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.Account,
                    L("Account"),
                    url: "Account",
                    icon: "fa fa-info",
                    requiredPermissionName:"AccountView",
                    requiresAuthentication: true

                    )

            )
            .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.Contact,
                    L("Contact"),
                    url: "Contact",
                    icon: "fa fa-info"
                    )
            );
    }
```

Adding breakpoints shows that the PermissionChecker is initialized as is the AuthProvider. Unfortunately, the navigation doesn't show the protected items even though I am authenticated and have valid role claims. The IsGrantedAsync method is never called. I tried setting the nav items with requiresAuthentication = true and false and neither changed anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're referring to Module Zero documentation but not using Module Zero.

If you don't store users, then it may not make sense to store user permissions.

You can implement `IPermissionChecker` to check permissions from claims.

```cs
public class PermissionChecker : IPermissionChecker, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public PermissionChecker(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(string permissionName)
    {
        // Get user
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        // Get claims of type "role"
        var roleClaims = user.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "role");

        // Check for applicable permission based on role permissions
        // ...
    }

    public Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(UserIdentifier user, string permissionName)
    {
        return IsGrantedAsync(permissionName);
    }
}
```

Since `AuthorizationHelper` checks `AbpSession.UserId`, you'll have to override its method.

```
public class NonUserAuthorizationHelper : AuthorizationHelper
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationConfiguration _authConfiguration

    public NonUserAuthorizationHelper(IFeatureChecker featureChecker, IAuthorizationConfiguration authConfiguration)
        : base(featureChecker, authConfiguration)
    {
        _authConfiguration = authConfiguration;
    }

    public override async Task AuthorizeAsync(IEnumerable<IAbpAuthorizeAttribute> authorizeAttributes)
    {
        if (!_authConfiguration.IsEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        // if (!AbpSession.UserId.HasValue)
        // {
        //     throw new AbpAuthorizationException(
        //         LocalizationManager.GetString(AbpConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "CurrentUserDidNotLoginToTheApplication")
        //     );
        // }

        foreach (var authorizeAttribute in authorizeAttributes)
        {
            await PermissionChecker.AuthorizeAsync(authorizeAttribute.RequireAllPermissions, authorizeAttribute.Permissions);
        }
    }
}
```

And then replace it in the `PreInitialize` method of your `*.Core` module.

```
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuthorizationHelper, NonUserAuthorizationHelper>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right about Module Zero. The documentation is pretty unclear about the difference. Apparently it only gets included if you select the user stuff when downloading the template?

Comment: Do you know if I can leverage that model with the menus (RequiredPermissionName)

Comment: Yes, just implement `IPermissionChecker`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: I rewrote it to handle the permission checking myself, but this is the best solution.